# Sonarcloud - Sonar warning - Accept button - "Valid issue but won't be fixed now, it's acceptable for a while."

Tags: sonarqube, sonarcloud

GIVEN:

- I created a pull request (PR)
- Sonarcloud scanned the PR
- Sonarcloud attached a warning to the PR

WHEN:

- I click the Accept button ("Valid issue but won't be fixed now, it's acceptable for a while.")

[image]

THEN:

- Does next time I create a PR touching the block of code that originally generated the warning, Sonar will re-display the warning?
- Or I will never see the warning again?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally tested it and arrived to this conclusion:

- The Accepted status will remain "Accepted" unless manually changed to "Re-open"
- So next time I create a PR touching the block of code
  that originally generated the warning, Sonar will re-display the warning (if I have not previously changed the status to Re-open
- Note that all "Accepted" warnings are still available from Sonarcloud app